# How can I element-wise multiply tensors with different dimensions?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor `expanded_mask`, which has a size of `torch.Size([1, 208])` and another one `inputs` which has a size of `torch.Size([1, 208, 161])`.

I want to elementwise multiply `expanded_mask` and `input` such that all 161 elements of the third dimension are multiplied with the 208 elements of `expanded_mask`.

As per [jodag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2790047/jodag)'s answer, I tried:

```
masked_inputs = expanded_mask.unsqueeze(2) * inputs
```

`inputs` is:

```
tensor([1.8851e-02, 4.4921e-02, 7.5260e-02, 3.8994e-02, 3.5651e-02, 3.0457e-02,
        1.2933e-02, 2.5496e-02, 2.3260e-04, 2.4903e-03, 6.5678e-03, 1.0501e-02,
        1.2387e-02, 1.9434e-03, 1.0831e-03, 6.5691e-03, 5.3792e-03, 9.1925e-03,
        1.8146e-03, 4.9215e-03, 1.4623e-03, 9.4454e-03, 1.0504e-03, 3.3749e-03,
        2.1361e-03, 8.0782e-03, 1.7916e-03, 1.1577e-03, 1.1246e-04, 2.2520e-03,
        2.2255e-03, 2.1072e-03, 9.8782e-03, 2.2909e-03, 2.9957e-03, 5.8540e-03,
        1.1067e-02, 9.0582e-03, 5.6360e-03, 6.3841e-03, 5.9298e-03, 1.9501e-04,
        2.7967e-03, 3.5786e-03, 9.2363e-03, 8.3934e-03, 8.8185e-04, 5.4591e-03,
        2.2451e-04, 2.2307e-03, 2.4871e-03, 3.6736e-03, 1.3842e-04, 2.7455e-03,
        6.2199e-03, 1.1924e-02, 9.5953e-03, 1.6939e-03, 4.1919e-04, 9.3509e-05,
        1.8351e-03, 6.3350e-04, 1.1076e-03, 1.5472e-03, 1.2104e-03, 3.1803e-04,
        8.6507e-04, 3.0083e-03, 2.8435e-03, 1.6740e-03, 8.1023e-05, 7.5767e-04,
        9.1442e-04, 2.0204e-03, 1.3987e-03, 3.7729e-03, 5.2012e-04, 2.0367e-03,
        1.5177e-03, 1.6948e-03, 9.5833e-04, 1.2050e-03, 1.8356e-03, 9.4503e-04,
        4.8612e-04, 1.6844e-04, 1.2222e-04, 1.7526e-03, 2.6397e-04, 1.3026e-03,
        1.0704e-03, 3.6407e-04, 1.3135e-03, 2.6665e-03, 1.8639e-03, 3.0385e-05,
        1.0212e-03, 7.6236e-04, 1.7878e-03, 2.4298e-03, 7.2158e-05, 1.2488e-03,
        2.1347e-03, 3.9256e-03, 3.1436e-03, 3.1648e-03, 3.4657e-03, 1.3746e-03,
        1.6927e-03, 1.0794e-03, 8.8152e-04, 1.1757e-04, 3.2254e-04, 4.1866e-04,
        9.2787e-04, 2.0020e-03, 1.4813e-03, 1.1912e-03, 2.4577e-03, 2.2247e-03,
        1.7862e-03, 1.7460e-03, 1.4388e-03, 4.3175e-04, 6.7808e-04, 2.6875e-04,
        3.6475e-04, 8.7643e-04, 3.6790e-04, 2.1274e-04, 6.3725e-04, 2.0949e-03,
        2.4069e-03, 1.7348e-03, 1.0026e-03, 1.2451e-03, 4.7888e-04, 5.9790e-04,
        1.4343e-03, 4.0900e-03, 1.0176e-03, 5.5178e-04, 2.0624e-03, 1.2878e-03,
        6.9607e-04, 4.3259e-04, 1.8573e-03, 7.5521e-04, 5.2949e-04, 3.4758e-04,
        4.7898e-04, 7.5599e-04, 6.0631e-04, 1.7585e-03, 1.8156e-03, 3.2421e-04,
        8.9446e-04, 7.2131e-04, 6.2817e-04, 1.0827e-03, 2.0211e-03],
       device='cuda:0')
```

`expanded_mask` is:

```
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
         1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<AsStridedBackward>)
```

then `masked_inputs` is:

```
tensor([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
```

Looks like the `1`'s isn't being multiplied through.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but doesn't `expanded_mask.unsqueeze(2) * inputs` produce the result you're asking for?

Comment: I'm not sure what `unsqueeze` does

Comment: it inserts a unitary dimension to make `expanded_mask` a size `[1, 154, 1]` tensor, then the multiplication implicitly relies on numpy-like broadcasting semantics to produce your result.

Comment: Okay - great. If you post as an answer, I can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of using broadcasting:

```
import torch

mask = torch.tensor([[1, 0, 1]])
inputs = torch.randn(1, 3, 2)
masked = inputs * mask[..., None]

print(mask)
print(inputs)
print(masked)
```

result:

```
tensor([[1, 0, 1]])
tensor([[[ 2.2820,  2.7476],
         [-0.1738, -0.5703],
         [ 0.7077, -0.6384]]])
tensor([[[ 2.2820,  2.7476],
         [-0.0000, -0.0000],
         [ 0.7077, -0.6384]]])
```

The ellipsis operator denotes all dimensions, then None adds a dimension at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can rely on broadcasting semantics here. We start by using [`Tensor.unsqueeze(2)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=unsqueeze#torch.Tensor.unsqueeze) on `expanded_mask` to add a unitary dimension onto the end making it a size `[1, 154, 1]` tensor. Then the multiplication operation will implicitly use numpy-like [broadcasting semantics](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html) to multiply each of the 161 channels of `inputs` with `expanded_mask`.

So the final result is

```
expanded_mask.unsqueeze(2) * inputs
```

Comment: @Shamoon Please elaborate.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: the `inputs` you posted isn't size [1,154, 161] as you stated in the question.

Comment: I mean, the `inputs` you printed isn't even a multi-dimensional array, its a size `[208]` tensor, can you post the result of `inputs.size()`

Comment: Ahhhh - I printed `inputs[0][0]` and `masked_inputs[0][0]` as well

Comment: @Shamoon k i'll check something be back shortly

Comment: The mask is size 208 so its being applied to the second layer. I.e. if you print inputs[0,:,0] and compare to masked_inputs[0,:,0] you should see that the mask has been applied to the input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210458/discussion-between-shamoon-and-jodag).